# Appirater methods are not being called

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, appirater

I'm using Appirater and am very excited by the functionality, but unfortunately I can't get it to work. I use the following code in the appDelegate file when the app launches, as per instruction:

```
[Appirater appLaunched];
```

I put a breakpoint on that line, and it is indeed getting called, but none of my breakpoints within the Appirater class actually hit at all. I had put a second breakpoint within the appLaunched method within the Appirater.m file and it never hits. Any advice on what might be going on here is appreciated. I tried setting debug to YES, changing the days till prompt to 0, but these should not even matter, since the first method that's supposed to hit within Appirater does not even seem to be doing so.

Yes, I imported Appirater.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you get a warning that say that above code is deprecated?

Also don't forget you need to initiate it with some defaults values (just random values):

```
[Appirater setAppId:appID];
[Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:0;

[Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:5];

[Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:0];

[Appirater setUsesAfterReminding:10];
```

And finally :

```
[Appirater appLaunched:YES];
```

I would also implement :

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForegroundNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [Appirater appEnteredForeground:YES];
```

}

The pop up will show after setUsesUntilPrompt numbers of times either by coming to foreground or by app launches if you did implement the willEnterForeground notification.

Comment: I did notice that appLaunched is deprecated earlier, so now I changed it to '[Appirater appLaunched:YES];' as you suggested. None of the methods within Appirater are getting called yet though. I didn't think setting any of those values were necessary since they had default values set in the Appirater.m class already. I have changed those manually, and have debug set to YES.

Comment: I edited my post with some real values, make sure you did registered for the notification. Launce the app 5 times or go background/foreground 5 times, it should pop up. I have used Appriter for 12 apps, so it should work.

Comment: I think the problem might extend beyond the basic configuration though. I put an NSLog statement in the 'appLaunched:(BOOL)canPromptForRating'as well as breakpoints, and the statement is not being printed and the breakpoints are also not being hit. As for the last bit of NSNotification, did you implement this in the appDelegate.m file? Would that have any effect on the whole thing?

Comment: If you could do a sample project in github or something similar, I can have a look of what you try to do and help you make it work, as I said, I used this one many times. ( I don't know if this kind of comment is acceptable by StackOverflow).

Answer (score 0):

I found out last night that the plugin package was working after all when I was showing a friend my app and the rating request appeared. I still don't know why none of the breakpoints within that class hit, but maybe it's because they are all static methods? Either way, If you have a similar issue, just hang in there and see if it works after trying it a bit.